# Alexa or Assistant Voice deeplink to open website

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, actions-on-google

I'm a non developer!  I'm hoping that there is an easy way we can add voice to deeplink to our webapp so elderly people can say "ok google, i'm happy to chat, show me who is nearby" and they will be shown the webpage on a Android phone or Display screen

Here's the webpage: https://www.happytochatcafe.com/find-nearby-chatters-1

Please tell me this can be done by just adding a URL to Assistant Actions or Alexa Skills :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is mixed. Yes, you can do this with the Assistant, although exactly how you do it depends on exactly what you're trying to do and what devices you expect your users to have. But it isn't possible to have a direct outbound link on Alexa.

The simplest way on the Assistant is to send a response that includes a [Basic Card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) that has a link to your site.

But this assumes that your user is using the Assistant through a device that has a screen (currently most Android phones and iOS devices with the Assistant installed, possibly including the just announced Smart Display in the future). You can detect if they are using such a device by checking the [surface capabilities](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#runtime-surface-capabilities) during a conversation. If this isn't a screen-capable conversation, you can [request to transfer](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations) to one that is capable.